# std::pow in static_assert triggers error C2057?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, static-assert

The following code in Visual Studio 2013 causes an error C2057:

```
#include <cmath>

int main() {
    static_assert(std::pow(2, 2) < 5, "foobar");
    return 0;
}
```

> error C2057: expected constant expression

If I compile under GCC `-std=c++0x` it works fine. http://ideone.com/2c4dj5

If I replace the `std::pow(2, 2)` with `4`, it also compiles under Visual Studio 2013.

- Is this a VS2013 bug?
- How can I work around this?

Comment: Visual C++ 2013 does not support `constexpr`.  But even if it did, `pow` is not required to be `constexpr`, so your code is at best nonportable and relies on implementation extensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) is not a `constexpr` function. The reason GCC accepts your code is because it offers a [builtin version](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) of `pow`, which evaluates the function at compile time since the arguments are known. If you add the `-fno-builtin` flag to the GCC command line, your code [fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6648a121517b388). The error message is as expected:

> error: non-constant condition for static assertion

So, this is not a VS2013 bug, but the effect of a GCC optimization. clang [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b68f697bb29296d0) the code either.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to implement your own `pow` as a constexpr function.

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T _pow(T x, size_t y) {
    return y ? x * _pow(x, y-1) : 1;
}
```

This implementation is very simple, but should work in your use-case.